# Nested loop dont work well

Tags: pyqgis

I am creating a plugin but my nested loop does not work well and I do not know why. How can I do this?

In PyQGIS the loops are different from the Python?

I have 2 inner loops inside a for loop, but my console ignores something, and I don't understand why?

In this case the loop ignores the points that I have on TFEA iterator.

I wrote the following code:

```py
for f in intersecting_features:
    print("a")
    layer.select(f.id())
    TFEA = point_of_study_feature.getFeatures()
    dist = 500
    for p in TFEA:
        print("b")
        analyze_feature_point = processing.run("qgis:pointsalonglines",{'INPUT':processing.run("native:saveselectedfeatures", {'INPUT':layer,'OUTPUT':'memory:'})["OUTPUT"],'DISTANCE':1,'START_OFFSET':0,'END_OFFSET':0,'OUTPUT':'memory:'})["OUTPUT"].getFeatures()
        
        for q in analyze_feature_point:
            dist_data = distance.measureLine(p.geometry().asPoint(), q.geometry().asPoint())
            if(dist_data < dist):
                
                dist = dist_data
    if (f["Z_MAX_ED"] - ((dist)*0.1)) >= select_feature["Z_MAX_ED"]:
        
        f.setAttributes([f["IDP"], dist, f'Sombreador: {f["IDP"]} (Z_MAX_OBST= {f["Z_MAX_ED"]}, dista {dist}m); Z_MAX_SOMBREAMENTO={(f["Z_MAX_ED"] - ((dist)*0.1))}m >= {select_feature["Z_MAX_ED"]}m.'])
        pr.addFeature(f)
```

Comment: If `point_of_study_feature` is empty it will not go into `for p in TFEA` loop. Try `point_of_study_feature.isValid()` and `point_of_study_feature.featureCount()`

Comment: @BERA i detected the problem! i have a nested loop where the first for loop is an list and the 2 inner lops are iterators, and when i do 'run', i dosent know why, but the the loops dont work whell. So i pass this iterators to lists and that resolve my problem! :) thanks anyway